# Can the 8th generation Intel Core mobile CPU be passively cooled like the 7th generation?

Tags: cpu, cooling, overheating, heatsink, silent-cooling

Intel Core mobile CPUs (such as the i5 7200U) have been utilized in fanless mini PCs.

Examples:

- [AZULLE Inspire Fanless Barebone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0776QX6VL)
- [ZOTAC ZBOX C Series](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07237NPWH)
- [Intel Dawson Canyon Fanless NUC](https://www.logicsupply.com/ml100g-31/)

Though the 8th generation was released a year ago, [a thorough search](https://www.google.com/search?q=fanless+(8650U+OR+8559U+OR+8550U+OR+8350U+OR+8269U+OR+8259U+OR+8250U)) for a fanless mini PC using a mobile (U-series) CPU of this generation seems to indicate that it is not offered anywhere.

Can the 8th generation Intel Core U-series CPU be passively cooled like the 7th generation (using only a heat sink)?

UPDATE - Aug 22:
This week, a new product was launched by INCTEL Technology in China:

[Partaker B16 Fanless Mini PC With Intel Core i5 8250U](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Partaker-B16-DDR4-Fanless-Mini-PC-WIN10-Mini-PC-With-Intel-Core-i5-8250U-HDMI-VGA/32916123684.html)

But I don't know if an expert will test it to verify its cooling capability, or at least decide by looking into the specs and design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The market for passive mini-PCs hasn't yet caught up with these newer processors. Fanless desktops are a relatively small niche, so the product cadence may not be as fast as that of mainstream consumer hardware. Even so, there are technical changes that make equipping a fanless mini-PC with an 8th generation processor more difficult than with a 7th generation part.

The 8th generation Core processors feature upgraded specs which may make them more difficult to cool under load. Core i5 and i7 U-series processors now have four cores rather than the two in previous generations. Even though the nominal TDP is still 15W for most U-type parts, the minimum cTDP has increased to 10W (previous chips went down to 7.5W), and the new quad-core chips often run closer to full power for longer. Thermal solutions for low-power systems are often designed to accommodate only short bursts of high loads, which means they would need to be redesigned for the new chips. (There are even lower power Y-type processors but these are slower and not yet available as 8th generation parts.)